# JPA - @Version - increase on read

Tags: jpa, optimistic-locking, optimistic-concurrency

I have implemented a simple entity ejb with a @version annotation. I expect that the version number will increase after each update of an entity.

```
@Version
public Integer getVersion() {
    return version;
}
public void setVersion(Integer version) {
    this.version = version;
}
```

But this seems not to work as expected.
Also each time when I read an entity, the version number increases automatically(!?). I expect that the version only increases after a commit?

Can anybody explain why my version increases also on reads?

Comment: Which type of locking strategy are you using & lock mode applied to entity.

Comment: I have not set any locking in my code. I have once set FlushModeType.COMMIT in my EJB which is dealing with the entities. But this seems not to have any influence. 

`manager.setFlushMode(FlushModeType.COMMIT);`

I am running GlassFish 3.1.1 and using a MySQL database with an XADataSource

Comment: Include the code for your read and the SQL log for the commit.  Ensure you are not changing the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I found the reason for the strange behavior.
The problem occurs during a method where I copy all values from my (still attached) entity into a detached domain model object. This all works well, since I read an attached entity contaning a complexe data structure (a vector containg HashMaps). I copied this values with the .addAll method from the List interface:

```
List activePropertyValue = (List)mapEntry.getValue();
// value contains HashMaps!
List detachePropertyValue = new Vector();
detachePropertyValue.addAll(activePropertyValue);
```

But it seems that this changed the hash value from the attached entity data property. So after all the entity was updated in the database, and the version number increases.

I solved the problem by detaching the entity before I copy all values:

```
manager.detach(aEntity);
.....
List activePropertyValue = (List)mapEntry.getValue();
// value contains HashMaps!
List detachePropertyValue = new Vector();
detachePropertyValue.addAll(activePropertyValue);
```

Comment: I had a similar problem and I fixed it adding equals/hashcode methods to my model. I had an @ElementCollection annotated collection and it got updated during read. Adding equals and hashcode to elements of collection fixed it. I managed to fix it quick thanks to your answer. Thank you!